# How to cross a column in a matrix!

Tags: matrices

I need some help. I need to draw horizontal lines all across row 1 and 3, and vertical lines all across columns 2 and 4.

I'm aware I can use `\makebox[0pt][l]{\rule[0.1cm]{0.19\textwidth}{0.7pt}}` to create horizontal lines. However, I don't know how to draw the vertical lines.

In advance, Thank you!

This is the matrix:

```
\(
\text{Matriz reducida}=
\begin{pmatrix}
- & 3 & 0 & 2 & 0 \\ 
5 & - & 4 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 2 & - & 0 & 1 \\
4 & 0 & 2 & - & 1 \\
4 & 0 & 2 & 0 & -
\end{pmatrix}
\)
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).